# Android JSON Parsing using asp .net

Tags: java, android, asp.net, json

I want to parse JSON in android. The problem is that, my web service is written in Asp .net. I tried to get JSON data as, when a web service is written in php. But I did't get result. I am attaching my code below.
**WebRequest class for http handling**

```
public class WebRequest {

        public static String getData(String url){
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            URL obj = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("URL :: " + url);
                obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    // print result
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("GET request not worked");
                }



            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("login issue", e.toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response.toString();

        }

        public static String postData(String data,String url){
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            URL obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                // For POST only - START
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                os.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                // For POST only - END

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;


                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    // print result
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("POST request not worked");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return response.toString();

        }
}
```

**Main Activity which contains AsyncTask**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView im;
    Button b1;
    TextView t1;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String img_url;
    JSONArray ja=null;
    String s;

    String url="http://qutofv2.anathothonline.us/json.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        im= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new getImage().execute(url);

            }
        });
    }

    private class getImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            s=WebRequest.getData(params[0]);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            try{
                JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(file_url);
                ja=jo.getJSONArray("Classifieds");
                JSONObject c=ja.getJSONObject(0);
                img_url=c.getString("url");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+file_url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch(JSONException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            t1.setText(img_url);

        }
    }
}
```

Anybody please help.....

Comment: You posted a huge dump of code, but didn't say what the problem was or where it occurs. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no error in the code. The result is not getting. Thats the only problem.

Comment: I don't know what "the result is not getting" means. What do you expect to happen, and what is happening?

Comment: your url extension is .php and you said you are calling .net webservice ?? strange @ThomasMKurialassery.

Comment: first check weather you are getting any response from your url or not , use rest postman client in browser for that. pass url and what ev the parameter with this and verify the response.